# Конфликт jquery и bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, bootstrap4, fancybox

Я совсем не силён в js, поэтому пользуюсь готовыми решениями.

У меня сборщик gulp, верстаю с помощью bootstrap 4.
js из "коробки" используется только для навигации (гамбургера).
Я хотел воспользоваться плагином fancybox для организации галереи на будущем сайте, однако ничего не получается.

Что я имею:

1. Файл main.min.js, который формируется сборщиком gulp.

Что я делаю:

1. Подключаю jquery (подключал разные версии, подключал как до файла main.min.js так и после)
2. Создаю html разметку, как пример:

```
<a id="single_image" href="image_big.jpg"><img src="image_small.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

3. Запускаю скрипт в head

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* This is basic - uses default settings */
    
    $("a#single_image").fancybox();
});
```

Файл head.html выглядит следующим образом:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css">
<title>Стартовая страница</title>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5504bc3ed9.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

/* This is basic - uses default settings */

$("a#single_image").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

На выходе - галерея не работает. Изображения открываются отдельными страницами.
В console вылезает следующие ошибки:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дайте код скрипта подключиеня `fancybox` ну и вызова. Очевидно что вы не там подключили или не подключили `fancybox`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц обновил стартовое сообщение

Comment: попробуйте подключить в таком порядке скрипты: jquery, fancybox, main

Comment: @Skywave не помогло)
скажем, проблема решилась, но очень прошу Вас прокомментировать)
1. т.к. я использую gulp, то в файле main.js я увидел кучу импортируемых файлов, в т.ч. jquery.

2. я залез на сайт fancybox и увидел, как установить пакет через npm. Установил

3. Подключил, соответственно, fancybox.

4. Заработало...

Подскажите, почему вручную не подключалось-то?(

Comment: а что находится внутри main.min.js? отключите его пока, для fancybox он не нужен вроде

Comment: @Skywave внутри находиться jquery + js библиотеки bootstrap. Отключая его - не работает навигационная панель, сверстанная на bootstrap.
Я обновил предыдущий комментарий, вроде как заработало, но почему - для меня загадка(

Comment: Если в main.min.js уже есть jquery, то его не надо подключать отдельно

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему у вас несколько ошибок:

1. Несоответствие версий jQuery и используемых библиотек: последний Bootstrap 4.3 требует версию **jQuery >=3.3.1**, а fancibox 1.3 нужна версия **jQuery < 1.9**
2. Вы цепляете к странице jQuery дважды - первый раз тегом `<script>`, второй раз из main.min.js. соответственно, из них двоих работать без костылей будет только одна, скорее всего та, что позже подгрузилась, но для уверенности можно в консоли DevTools выполнить код  `$().jquery;` или `$.fn.jquery`, который покажет используемую версию jQuery.

Судяпо ошибке, которую вы получаете, предположу, что используется jQuery >= 1.9, т.к. свойство `$.browser` в котором и лежал флаг `msie` [было удалено начиная с версии 1.9](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/).

### Возможные решения

1. На мой взглян, оптимальный вариант - найти другую библиотеку на замену устаревшей, уже как 9 лет, `fancybox 1.3`. В своем текущем проекте я использую `magnific-popup`, но есть множество других.
2. Так же, можно использовать более старую версию Bootstrap или отказаться от него совсем. *Но я бы не рекомендовал использовать устаревшие библиотеки, что fancybox, что jQurey.*
3. Ну и самое нерациональное, в рамках озвученной задачи - использовать `$.noConflict()`, как то так:

```html
<!-- грузим js 1.4 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jq_1_4 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- грузим main.min.js, в котором старшая верися jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.min.js"></script>

<!-- fancybox -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

/* This is basic - uses default settings */

    jq_1_4("a#single_image").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

Comment: спасибо, проблема была решена переходом на новую версию fancybox, с поддержкой более поздних версий jquery. Но ваш ответ структурировал кашу в моей голове, за что я Вам безмерно благодарен!